# In JavaCC, how to reduce the priority of regular expressions?

Tags: compiler-construction, javacc

Let me clarify my question with a concrete example:

First, I have a token:

```
<T_SELECT:"SELECT">
```

Second, I have a regular expression token:

```
<T_TABLE_NAME:~[","]>
```

Third, I have a production:

```
<T_SELECT> <T_TABLE_NAME> (","<T_TABLE_NAME>)*
```

Finnaly, I want to parse the string like:

```
SELECT TABLE1
```

My problem is:
Instead of consume `SELECT` and then `TABLE1`, JavaCC ends up with taking `SELECT TABLE1` as `<T_TABLE_NAME>`!

Obviously I was expecting it excatly consumes `SELECT` because I have defined a token called `<T_SELECT: "SELECT">`

What can I do to tell JavaCC to consume the exact string I have defined instead of regular expressions?

Comment: Are table names with unescaped/unquoted spaces supposed to be allowed in your syntax?

Comment: Yes, in our syntax, unquotes spaces are allowed.

Comment: Do you intend that that table names can only be one character long?  In the example " TABLE1" is 7 characters long.  But the regular expression `~[","]` will only match strings that are one character long.  See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

That's almost certainly not what you want to do, since it would turn `selection` into `select` `ion`.

`~[","]` will match anything other than a comma, including space and newline characters. That can't be right either, since table names don't start with (or contain) space characters.

You need to match and ignore whitespace and restrict names to legal name characters.

Comment: In our sytax it is allowed to contain spaces in the table name. We have defined a query language for our own system.

Comment: @qinqjinlyc even if a table name consists of several words, it seems unlikely that the space betwen `select` and `my table` would be part of the name. (And what if someone put two spaces after `select`?) Normally, languages which allow multiword names consider them to be lists of words rather than literal stri gs with spaces, so that`my table` and `my  table` are the same name. Allowing keywords to run into the next symbol (my `selection` example) is even less common. And for good reason

Comment: Do you mean `select`, `i`, `o`, `n`?

Comment: @theodore: Using a comma to delimit tokens it would be `select`,`ion`. Although it's true that I am assuming that OP just forgot a repetition operator.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that the only lexical rules you have are these

```
TOKEN { <T_SELECT:"SELECT"> }
TOKEN { <T_TABLE_NAME:~[","]> }
TOKEN { <T_COMMA: "," > }
```

The third rule is implicit because you have the string "," in your grammar. I'm making it explicit here.   Now if the character sequence to be parsed is

```
 "SELECT TABLE1" ,
```

the sequence will be lexed as follows

- First a T_SELECT is found.
- Then 7 T_TABLE_NAME tokens.
- Then and an EOF token.

I.e.:

```
T_SELECT("SELECT")
T_TABLE_NAME(" ")
T_TABLE_NAME("T")
T_TABLE_NAME("A")
...
T_TABLE_NAME("1")
EOF
```

If your grammar consists of one rule

```
void select() : {} {
    <T_SELECT>
    <T_TABLE_NAME>
    (<T_COMMA> <T_TABLE_NAME>)* 
}   ,
```

then only the first two tokens will be matched.

If your grammar consists of one rule

```
void select() : {} {
    <T_SELECT>
    <T_TABLE_NAME>
    (<T_COMMA> <T_TABLE_NAME>)* 
    <EOF>   // I added an <EOF>
}   ,
```

then the example input has a syntax error and the parser will throw an exception.  For the third token the parser expects either a `T_COMMA` or an `EOF`, but it gets a `T_TABLE_NAME`.

---

I'm going to make some more assumptions.

- First I'm going to assume that table names can consist of 0 or more characters rather than 1 character as in the OP.
- Second, I'm going to assume that table names can not contain newlines or linefeeds. Otherwise, there would be no way to terminate the `SELECT` queries except by hitting the end of the file.
- Third I'm going to assume that a newline or end of file terminates each `SELECT` query.
- Fourth I'm going to assume that the `SELECT` keyword is only used before a table name.

These are probably incorrect assumptions, but I need to make *some* assumptions to make sense of the question.

---

As a first change, I'll allow table names to be any length.  And I'll forbid newlines in table names as well as commas. And I'll make a new token to deal with any newlines.  The lexical rules are now

```
TOKEN { <T_SELECT:"SELECT"> }
TOKEN { <T_TABLE_NAME: (~[",","\n","\r"])* > }
TOKEN { <T_COMMA: "," > }
TOKEN { <T_NEWLINE: ("\n" | "\n\r" | "\r") > }
```

Now what's going to happen?  Again assume the input string is

```
"SELECT TABLE1"    ,
```

there is a prefix of length 6 that matches the rule

```
<T_SELECT:"SELECT">
```

and there are several (14 in fact) prefixes that match the rule

```
<T_TABLE_NAME: (~[",","\n","\r"])* >
```

Since the prefix of length 6 is matched by both rules, there are, in total, 14 prefixes that can be matched by at least one rule.

Of these 14 prefixes, the lexer will always choose the longest.  This is the maximal munch rule.  Therefore the sequence of tokens will be

```
T_TABLE_NAME("SELECT TABLE1") EOF
```

There is no way to turn off the maximal much rule. You can't win this game. You must cheat.

---

The way to cheat is to take out the competition.  Move the `T_TABLE_NAME` rule to a different lexical state.

You want to switch states after lexer sees the SELECT keyword.

Write your lexer rules like this:

```
TOKEN : { <T_SELECT: "SELECT"> : S_TABLE_NAME } 

<S_TABLE_NAME> TOKEN :
    { <T_TABLE_NAME:(~[",","\n","\r"])*> : S_TABLE_NAME 
    | <T_COMMA: "," } : S_TABLE_NAME
    | <T_NEWLINE: ("\n" | "\n\r" | "\r") : DEFAULT }
```

Now your production will be

```
void Select() : {} 
{ <T_SELECT>
  <T_TABLE_NAME>
  ( <T_COMMA> <T_TABLE_NAME>)*
  ( <T_NEWLINE> )? 
  <EOF>
}
```

If the input is

```
 "SELECT ABC, DEF\n"    ,
```

it will be lexed as follows

```
State          Token Produced
------------------------------
DEFAULT        T_SELECT("SELECT")
S_TABLE_NAME   T_TABLE_NAME( " ABC" )
S_TABLE_NAME   T_COMMA( "," )
S_TABLE_NAME   T_TABLE_NAME( " DEF" )
S_TABLE_NAME   T_NEWLINE( "\n" )
DEFAULT        EOF.
```

And it will parse without error.

Comment: Hi @Norvell, I tried your proposal and it can parse "select abc, def". How ever, in our syntax, there could be "from" after the tables, say, "select abc, def from somewhere". Then "from" will be deemed as part of "def". However, "from" is the keyword.

Comment: Your original post said that "a table name is any string of length 1 that does not contain a comma."  I guessed that that is not what you meant.  I gave an *example* alternative definition "a table name is a string not containing a comma, newline, or return".  That was just an example.  You are pointing out that my definition is not right because " def from somewhere" is not a table name. It's no surprise that my example is not exactly what you want.  If you can define in plain unambiguous English (with examples) which strings are table names, make a new question. Maybe someone can answer it.